# GCP API - same "failed to connect to all addresses" error from IAM and Ai Platform APIs

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam

I have a common error when trying to use two different GCP API libraries.  The context is that I'm making calls to verify resources being created properly - I'm not trying to create resources,  just trying to read them.  For both, I have the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set to the json file of the service account credentials.  I'm sure this means there is some common thing is missing from my authentication or code that I haven't seen in the documentation yet.  If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be awesome.

**Example one**:
using Google.Cloud.Iam.Admin.V1 calling the ListRoles method.  This code comes from the example in:

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Iam.Admin.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Iam.Admin.V1.IAMClient#Google_Cloud_Iam_Admin_V1_IAMClient_ListRoles_Google_Cloud_Iam_Admin_V1_ListRolesRequest_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_

Code:

```
23. // Create client
24. IAMClient iAMClient = IAMClient.Create();
25. // Initialize request argument(s)
26. ListRolesRequest request = new ListRolesRequest
27. {
28.     ParentAsResourceName = new UnparsedResourceName("//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/MYPROJECTID/datasets/test_hm_bigquery"),
29.     View = RoleView.Basic,
30.     ShowDeleted = false,
31. };
32. // Make the request
33. PagedEnumerable<ListRolesResponse, Role> response = iAMClient.ListRoles(request);
34. 
35. // Iterate over all response items, lazily performing RPCs as required
36. foreach (Role item in response)
37. {
38.     // Do something with each item
39.     Console.WriteLine(item);
40. }
```

Error shows when executing line 36 when trying to iterate through the response object.

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1646170431.164000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3159,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1646170431.164000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\transport\error_utils.cc","file_line":147,"grpc_status":14}]}")
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Cloud.Iam.Admin.V1.IAM.IAMClient.ListRoles(ListRolesRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.Sync(TRequest request, CallSettings perCallCallSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcPagedEnumerable`3.<AsRawResponses>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Terraform.Tests.BigQueryDatasetTests.Test() in C:\projects\Terraform.Tests\Terraform.Tests\BigQueryDatasetTests.cs:line 36
```

**Example two**:
using Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.  This code comes from

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.ModelServiceClient#Google_Cloud_AIPlatform_V1_ModelServiceClient_GetModel_Google_Cloud_AIPlatform_V1_ModelName_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_

```
19. ModelServiceClient modelServiceClient = ModelServiceClient.Create();
20. ModelName name = ModelName.FromProjectLocationModel("MYPROJECTID", "us-central1", "testhm");
21. Model response = modelServiceClient.GetModel(name);
```

Error shows when executing line 21

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1646171341.746000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3159,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1646171341.746000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\transport\error_utils.cc","file_line":147,"grpc_status":14}]}")
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.ModelService.ModelServiceClient.GetModel(GetModelRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<WithCallSettingsOverlay>b__1(TRequest req, CallSettings cs)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.Sync(TRequest request, CallSettings perCallCallSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.ModelServiceClientImpl.GetModel(GetModelRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.ModelServiceClient.GetModel(ModelName name, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Terraform.Tests.AiPlatformTests.AiModel_Test_Success() in C:\projects\Terraform.Tests\Terraform.Tests\AiPlatformTests.cs:line 21
```

To try and isolate the problem, I've also debugged it and used Fiddler to see traffic to and from.  I'm unable to see anything either way.  Just to make sure I had Fiddler set up right I made a simple HTTP call to github and saw the entry just fine.  So I'm a little baffled as to what's going on.

Comment: I don't have easy access to a .NET environment but `ParentAsResourceName` looks incorrect. This is a particularly confusing aspect of Google's APIs. Using [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest) for [`projects.roles.list`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.roles/list), you can see that `parent=projects/*`. So, if that is the method you want, `ParentAsResourceName` needs to be `projects/{PROJECT_ID}` where you replace `{PROJECT_ID}` with the desired project ID value.

Comment: With regards, authentication. If you're correct `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json`, then the client libraries automatically authenticate for you using those credentials. You **really** don't need to do anything else.

Comment: @DazWilkin - In the actual code I have the proper project_id.  I replaced the text for the purpose of this post.

Comment: Yes, understood but your `ParentAsResourceName` is, I think, incorrect.

Comment: In my experience, this error almost *always* there's a network problem - typically a corporate proxy that doesn't support HTTP/2 (which gRPC uses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would close off this question that I posed because I found that the answer was something I suspected all along: as Jon Skeet noted above it was the network.  The client's environment was such that there was an updated SSL certificate that was needed and several environment variables that needed to point to it.  It took a while to get the right people at the client to tell me where the document was that showed how the workstation was supposed to be configured.  I mistakenly believed this was done by their IT staff when the computer was set up (I'm RDPing into it).  Anyways, all's well that ends well.  DazWilkin, thank you for your efforts to help me resolve this!